# How to generate headers with sources for gSoap? (WS-Security)

Tags: c++, c, soap, gsoap

I'm trying to add support for WS-Security so that basic authorization is possible in the server request header.

I checked this doc https://www.genivia.com/doc/wsse/html/wsse.html

The problem I encountered was at the next stage. I need to generate using **soapcpp2**, but it keeps writing in the console[image]

Full command **soapcpp2**:

```
/c/Users/sultan/.conan2/p/b/gsoapfb40d333bc97e/b/build/Debug/soapcpp2.exe -CL -I C:\\Users\\sultan\\.conan2\\p\\b\\gsoapfb40d333bc97e\\b\\src\gsoap\\import;C:\\Users\\sultan\\.conan2\\p\\b\\gsoapfb40d333bc97e\\b\\src\gsoap\\custom sdp_service_multi.h
```

Before I invoke wsdl2h in console

```
/c/Users/sultan/.conan2/p/b/gsoapfb40d333bc97e/b/build/Debug/wsdl2h.exe -s -o sdp_service_multi.h SdpServiceMulti.wsdl
```

How to correctly generate source codes with WS-Security support?

Comment: I see that c is tagged, so if you have some c code please share it.... thx.

Comment: Excuse me, but what is the code? I'm still only at the stage of generating it. If the output generates pure C, then that’s also good. Or do you need the code after the wsdl2h generation step?

Comment: hi.  Sorry, I saw that C was tagged in your question and so I thought you might be doing some programming in C for this -- but I've apparently misunderstood, my bad.  Have a great day...